# iOS App on iPad Air Wrong Rotation

Tags: ios, ipad

As iOS developer I have created an App for my client. It is locked in landscape mode all the time. Everything works fine on my iPad 2, but for some unknown reason it is stuck in portrait on my clients device, an iPad Air 2 with iOS Version 9.3.2 (to which I currently have no access). I suspect a software glitch on the iPad Air, but would like to make sure that the fault is not with me before suggesting a reboot or even a rollback. My question therefore is: Which XCode settings should I check to make sure everything is fine with my app and the fault is with the device? I'd appreciate any experience shared.

Comment: Is it working correctly on every other device just not the client's iPad?  In Xcode, check the target's `Deployment Info` and make sure `Upside down` is not the *only* thing checked.

Comment: Have you checked that they haven't locked the orientation on their device?

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my test devices. And they haven't locked the orientation. Even if they'd have, the app should display in landscape (as far as I know).